# infinite sum as integral for the counting measure

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $u: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive sequence. Then it is true that 
$$
\int u d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty u(n). 
$$
For the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure.  The proof uses monotone convergence theorem, and goes as follows:

Take the measure space $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^\infty \delta_j}_{\mu})$. 
Let $u: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a positive function ($u \geq 0$).

We define 
$$
u_n(k) = 
\begin{cases}
u(k) & k \leq n, \\
0 & k > n. 
\end{cases}
$$
For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u_n$ is a normal function since we have $u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u(k)1_{\{k\}}$. Thus, the approximation cuts of $u$ after $n$. Moreover, we have 
$$
\int u_n d\mu = I_\mu(f) = \sum_{k=1}^n u(k) \mu(\{k\}) = \sum_{k=1}^n u(k). 
$$
Since we have $0 \leq u_n \uparrow u$, then it follows by MCT that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{N}} u d\mu \stackrel{MTC}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int u_n d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty u(k). 
$$

Now can someone tell me under what condition this is true if $u: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily positive?

Comment: I think you confuses the definitions. The equality holds by the definition of the integral and has nothing to do with the monotone convergence theorem. Also if $u:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ then it is necessarily positive (again by definition).

Comment: Why it holds by definition?

Comment: Which definition of integration do you use?

Comment: For step functions / simple functions $f = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i 1_{A_i}$: $I_\mu(f) := \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \mu({A_i})$. For positive functions: $\int u d\mu := \sup\{I_\mu(g): g \leq u, g $ simple $\} \in [0,\infty]$. For general functions: $\int u d\mu = \int u^+d\mu - \int u^- d\mu$.

Comment: Alright so a simple function in this case is a function that is supported only on finitely many points. It is only left to understand why $\sup \{I_u(g):g\leq u, g \text{ simple} \} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_u(u_n)$ where $u_n$ is $u$ restricted to the first $n$ points (i.e. $u_n(k)=u(k)$ if $k\leq n$ and $0$ otherwise). Does it explain?

Comment: Indeed simple functions are defined on only finitely many sets. Yes, I think I see the idea, but in proving the above equation for the sum and the integral, my book uses the MCT to get the limit out of the integral.

Comment: That's a bit odd. Because I don't see any limit in your question. Try to read again what's written in the book, there must be a sequence of integrals or otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Wait a sec, let me state the proof here

Comment: I added the proof in the question

Comment: I see, well that also works, I guess. Anyway, I don't understand your final question, do you ask whether the result holds if you let $u$ receive negative values?

Comment: Indeed, does this result hold for general $u$?

Comment: It holds for example if $\sum |u(n)| <\infty$. In this case you can permute the elements inside the sum (Are you aware of this result?)

Comment: Yes, I just found that.

Comment: So if the sum converges it is true right? and thus if $u$ is integrable, it seems.

Comment: If the sum convergence **absolutely** then it is true (See my answer). I'm quit certain it's wrong without the absolute value.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prove

> If $u(n)$ is a sequence such that $\sum_n |u(n)| <\infty$ then $\int u d\mu = \sum_n u(n)$

By the definition of integral we have $\int u d\mu = \int u^+ d\mu - \int u^- d\mu$

By what you just showed for $u^+,u^-$ we have $u^\pm = \sum_n u^\pm (n)$

Since the sum is uniformly convergence it is the same to sum from $1,2,...$ or to sum first the $n$ for which $u(n)>0$ and only then the $n$ for which $u(n)<0$.